# Change the back ground of my list (Eclipse.Android)

Tags: android, list

I´m making a projecto to android eclipse and I put a list in the beggining of my app.
I´m using a standard list of android (android.R.Layout.list.simple.list.item_1). The problem is when I change the layout, for example to (android.R.Layout.list.simple.list.item_2) or to any layout that I have in my app (ex:R.layout.about), the program give me an error(the app stopped unexpectedly).

here is part of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(

                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        MenuInicial.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        classes
```

Comment: What is the error ? Btw you're layout should be defined in a specific way, you can use whatever you want with the ArrayAdapter

Comment: Whenever *(the app stopped unexpectedly)*, look at the logcat output and include here in question.

Comment: Please share logcat output with us so that we can help you out

Comment: here is part of my logcat: 

12-18 09:27:16.614: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-18 09:27:16.614: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 09:27:16.614: E/AndroidRuntime(370): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem
12-18 09:27:16.614: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340).......and more..
12-18 09:27:16.614: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  ... 26 more
thanks

Comment: This is my fisrt error in my logcat when I change to another layout -> array adapter - you must supply a resource ID  for a text view

Answer (score 0):

You can use customadapter to do anything you want. Please [check this sample project](http://tugrulasik.com/2011/12/21/android-not-defteri-uygulamasi/) It will help you.

Comment: Yes, very interes-ting post, but I really want to know why I change the layout to .simple_list_item_2 instead of .simple_list_item_1 and the app stop :s ....

Comment: Please check this URL. list item 1 and 2 are different. http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:android_simple_list_item1_and_simple_list_item2:txt

Comment: oh, that is the reason why I receive the error "you must supply a resource ID for a textview"! do you know what can I do to fix this problem to use another layout from my app?

Comment: Use custom list view and do everything you want. This işs my suggestion. Other ways are not reliable.